# Why does pip -t not work on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: python, 15.04, python-2.7, pip

I've been having an odd problem with pip on Ubuntu 15.04. When I try to install anything using the "-t" option to put it in a specific directory, it fails with the following error:

`error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`

For instance, `pip install -t <directory> <package>` fails with this error.

My pip is version 1.5.6, and my Python version is 2.7.

I've run the exact same commands on my 14.10 systems with no issues, so I can only conclude that this is a problem which is particular to 15.04.

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/619838/edit) your question and add your command "to install anything using the "-t" option".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and what I noticed is that the pip in the default distro is old 1.5.6 the current released version being 7.1.0. Since is hard to track down the issue, looking there and there for the "needle in a hay stack" I removed it and installed it manually as suggested in the following :

This comment : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1093#issuecomment-103127883
referenced in this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460232/pip-list-crashes-with-an-assertionerror

Remove pip:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-pip
```

Download the install script :

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Install it back:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Link commands to bin :

```
sudo ln -s [PIP_HOME]/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
sudo ln -s [PIP_HOME]/bin/wheel /usr/local/bin/wheel
sudo ln -s [PIP_HOME]/bin/easy_install /usr/local/bin/easy_install
```

Where [PIP_HOME] is the directory of the pip package.

now when I run `pip -V` puts out :

```
pip 7.1.0 from /home/tiberiu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Back to my root problem the command `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib` success with the newest version.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to fix the problem.

Comment: /local/bin does not exist.
The overall solution is fine, however.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you link from usr/local/bin/pip to itself?

Comment: What is bootstrap.pypa.io and why should it be trusted?

Comment: @CoreyS. Yes the domain pypa.io is wierd indeed.  but the procedure is pointed in python.org (I didn't invented it). 
source : https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html 

> the Python Packaging Authority are the group of developers and documentation authors responsible for the maintenance and evolution of the standard packaging tools and the associated metadata and file format standards. They maintain a variety of tools, documentation, and issue trackers on both GitHub and BitBucket.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Tiberiu C's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/656166/439853) hit the nail on the head. I can't believe the `pip` in the distro is that old. However, those steps to resolve it seem like quite a bit of work so I wanted to propose that if you already have `easy_install` on your system as well, you can get away with implementing his solution with the line:

```
sudo easy_install -U pip
```

At first I tried to do a self-upgrade of `pip` with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

However, it will refuse to replace the distro version. But then I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/707633/439853) which pointed me to the solution above.