# Unable to upgrade pip

Tags: upgrade, python

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I was trying to upgrade pip but ran into this...

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=b108384a762825ec20345bb9b5b7209f
  Downloading pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

Any idea why?

Comment: try `apt` i.e.  `sudo apt-get install python-pip` to upgrade `pip`

Comment: hmmm... says its the most up-to-date version... is this because apt-get and pip get their packages form different sources?  (i.e. would that be a difference between apt-get and pypi?)

'python-pip is already the newest version.'

Comment: that means it is up to date...

Comment: except running: pip list --outdated pip returns the following: pip (Current: 1.5.4 Latest: 7.1.0)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-apt
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external python-apt to allow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
pip install -U pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

`-U` is shorthand for `--upgrade`.

---

**Old answer:**

The `apt` system and `PyPI` uses two different mechanisms.

In Ubuntu's repositories many modules of `python` are available as packages, but they are not much in numbers as compared to [PyPI (The Python Package Index)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). To remain consistent about upgrading a package you need to consider the method you have used initially used to install it.

So if you have installed a package (module) from `PyPI` using `pip` then you should used `pip` to upgrade the package from `PyPI` (including `pip` itself). On the other hand if you have used `apt` system to install a module (as package) you need to use `apt` to upgrade that again.

In a nutshell, run the following to upgrade `python-pip` to the latest version :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. python-pip doesn't upgrade pip, it only installs a very old version of pip in such as way that pip cannot upgrade itself.

Comment: @Cerin Did you read the answer thoroughly? `python-pip` is the package from the (official) Universe repository whereas `easy_install` installs from `PyPI`. As always the official repositories do not not contain the latest package to keep the system stable (and dependencies resolved).

Comment: @heemayl, OP asked how to upgrade pip and you effectively told them to install an old version of pip. The correct solution is to uninstall python-pip and install from PyPI. Installing python-pip does not upgrade pip.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  The OP says `$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip` didn't work.  Answer: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 23):

Try install it with `easy_install`:

```
easy_install -U pip
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is still valid? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404) on Stack Overflow asked on "Why use pip over easy_install?", in which one of the answers noted that: "The only good reason that I know of to use easy_install in 2015 is the special case of using Apple's pre-installed Python versions with OS X 10.5-10.8."

Comment: Focus on question, the question is 'Unable to upgrade pip', and I suggest way upgrade via easy_install, it work in Dec 2015, ok?

Comment: To downvoters, do explain why this answer was downvoted earlier? I managed to find a recent comment under [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/561377/37165), which is quoted here: " easy_install -U pip from ByteCommander suggestion worked for me. – Tampa Jun 1 at 12:23".  The `easy_install` method reportedly works for some users.

Comment: This worked for me (with `sudo`). Previously, `sudo apt-get install python-pip` was giving me `python-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4)` whereas 9.0.1 was available, but couldn't be installed by `pip install --upgrade pip` (which left the version unchanged at 8.1.1). After `easy_install` the version was upgraded.

Comment: Although this works, this does replace *system-managed files* with the newer `pip` version. A re-install of the `python-pip` package would replace the files again. Other code relying on the package version being present and correct could break (small but non-zero chance), and `easy_install` could add *extra* files that are not removed when in future upgrading `python-pip` to a newer version that may interfere and break things.

Comment: Even if the easy_install worked i don't really understand why both methods pip and python-pip didn't did the trick. Thx

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue for a long time and figured out the solution today. When you install pip via python-pip, you download from the deprecated Linux server. You should download from the python server. To solve this, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge pip
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo easy_install pip 
pip install pip --upgrade
```

Comment: thanks for explaining the source of the problem. i had to figure this out myself before scrolling down and seeing this answer.

Comment: These commands (2-3) are wrong.

Comment: @JoelGMathew need just word install after apt-get

Comment: After installing `python-setuptools` and `python-dev`, I still get `easy_install: command not found`.  Is there something I need to do for `easy_install` to be accessible from the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a conflict between a version of pip provided by a system package, like `python-pip`, and a version provided by PyPI through pip itself.

To fix this, simply remove `python-pip` with `sudo apt-get purge python-pip`.

If you had already used the old version of pip to install a newer version, this should leave the updated version in `/usr/local/bin`. If not, you can install the most recent version of Pip from scratch with:

### Pip for Python 2.7:

```
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7
```

### Pip for Python 3.x:

```
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

Comment: This one works for me, It turns out that I make mistake by removing python 2.7, then the python packages become missing, and I have to reinstall pip for python 3

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can edit your 'pip' script:

from root:

```
$ which pip  # -> prints 'pip' location

$ nano `which pip` # -> open with your editor, note the backticks!
```

replace the `__requires__` with your latests pip version like:

```
__requires__ = 'pip==7.1.2'
```

than edit line with 'load_entry_point' call to:

```
load_entry_point(__requires__, 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
```

and:

```
$pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

also, i have to update my **setuptools** package, to install some packages.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to upgrade. Basically:

1. Download the file `get-pip.py`
2. run `python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 1):

If `python-pip` installed from apt repositories with sudo user - run `sudo -H install --upgrade pip` , same for installing PIP modules .

Here the output from my console on 16.04

```
..... Successfully installed requests
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 672kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
:~$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 692kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-9.0.1
:~$
```

also see [What is the -H flag for pip? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619686/what-is-the-h-flag-for-pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619686/what-is-the-h-flag-for-pip)

Comment: I had this problem on a Lubuntu 16.04 system and it finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade your pip3 (for Python 3). 
Conversely, you can do `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip as well (for Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when working on a remote machine I was ssh'd into. I had just installed python 3, and was unable to get pip to upgrade, even though I'd attempted to upgrade via both pip AND apt-get.

Logging out of the remote server and logging back in fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a beginner so I'm not sure but probably is something related to the differences between python 2 and 3. I think that is not necessary to be a superuser but you can do it easily using `pip3` instead of `pip` also to upgrade `pip` :
`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem on upgrading pip 9.0.3 to 18.0 version.

So on upgrading first uninstallation happens and then the latest version is installed. However, I found that on your first attempt it says "successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.3"

On subsequent attempts, we get the same error. This is because the pip-9.0.3 is uninstalled. As with the accepted answer, I installed pip as an admin in my windows 10 system, got thee latest version and then all was well.

Hope this helps.