# Cannot upgrade pip behind proxy

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I've tried all the suggestions in this other question, but it just isn't working for me: [Unable to upgrade pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644911/unable-to-upgrade-pip)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and was able to install pip 1.0 using `apt`, but that version apparently has a bug which doesn't play nice with proxies, so I don't know how I can update it.

Here's what I'm getting in my console:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

### try #1

```
$ pip --proxy=$http_proxy install -U pip
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing complete log in /home/falconer_k/.pip/pip.log
```

### try #2

```
$ python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py --proxy=$http_proxy
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3:
UserWarning: Module pip was already imported from 
/tmp/tmpqbetIm/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py, but /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
is being added to sys.path from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.Verified
HTTPSConnection object at 0x392eed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[Errno -2] Name or service not known',))': /simple/pip/
```

I can access the `simple/pip` folder directly using the browser:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/

I also don't have the option to use a non-proxied connection.

Here's the contents of ~/.pip/pip.log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Tue May  3 15:33:22 2016
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip: timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip when looking for download links for pip
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for pip:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
No distributions at all found for pip
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 948, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pip
```

Comment: I was able to do this by tethering my internet connection to my laptop, then sharing that connection over ethernet to this machine to do the update using `pip install -U pip`. I'll leave it up in case someone else comes up against this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below

```
pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port <package Name>
```

for example

```
pip install --proxy=http://10.10.10.150/accelerated_pac_base.pac quandl
```