# Not uninstalling paramiko at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr

Tags: upgrade, pip

I am trying to upgrade paramiko on Ubuntu 16.04 4.4.0 with pip 8.1.1:

```
pip install -U paramiko
...
Installing collected packages: idna, setuptools, enum34, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, paramiko
  Found existing installation: idna 2.0
    Not uninstalling idna at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Found existing installation: setuptools 20.7.0
    Not uninstalling setuptools at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Found existing installation: enum34 1.1.2
    Not uninstalling enum34 at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Found existing installation: cryptography 1.2.3
    Not uninstalling cryptography at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Found existing installation: paramiko 1.16.0
    Not uninstalling paramiko at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[Full log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XxNd5c3zV_ZTZZbHdOcUI5bFU/view?usp=sharing)

Same issue if I try to upgrade pip itself.

Comment: How did you first install `paramiko`? I ask because this affects how you upgrade it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this issue affects all python packages. They were all primarily installed with apt-get.

Comment: It is a **bug related to 8.1.1** and **solved by 8.1.2**.

If you happen to encounter the same issue and you are unable to upgrade to 8.1.2, I have built the latest version and made it available in my [PPA][1].


  [1]: https://gitlab.com/jean-christophe-manciot/ppa

Answer (score 14):

I guess your problem is related to the problem discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644911/unable-to-upgrade-pip).

Try to delete `paramiko` package using `apt-get` first:
`apt-get remove python-paramiko`.

This should also work for updating `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
apt-get remove python-pip
```

Comment: Removing python-paramiko will also remove many other Ubuntu packages and software you may have running that rely on it, such as ansible, fabric, mysql workbench community etc

Comment: This helped me with html5lib.

Comment: Why `apt-get remove python-pip`?

Comment: After removing `python-pip`, pip no more works, obviously, so, why remove it?

Comment: @realtebo "The apt system and PyPI uses two different mechanisms." There are effectively two versions of pip after the upgrade so the old one can be safely removed.